# Function Extension

Tags: real-analysis, linear-programming

I am faced with a problem: Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ rational matrix, $c$ be a rational $n$-vector.
 Consider $f$: $f(u)=\max\{c^Tx|x\in S^u\}$, where $S^u:=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n|Ax\le u\}$ and $f$ is defined over the set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ where $S=\{u\in\mathbb{R}^m|S^u\neq\phi\}$.
Assume $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is bounded for all $u\in S$. Show that there exists $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
(1)  $g(u)$ is finite valued for $u\in \mathbb{R}^m$,
(2) $g(u)=f(u)$ $\forall u\in S$
(3) $f$ is non-decreasing: if $u^1\ge u^2$ componentwise, then $g(u^1)\ge g(u^2)$
(4) $g$ is superadditive: $g(u^1)+g(u^2)\le g(u^1+u^2)$

I am thinking about whether I could use the following theorem to extend $g$ to $\mathbb{R}^m-S$, but I am confusing about how to define it strictly.
Let A be an integral $m\times n$ integral matrix (by eliminating the denominators, we can do this in our problem) such that each subdeterminant of $A$ is at most $\Delta$ in absolute value, let $b',b''$ be column $m-$vectors, and let $c$ be a row $n-$vector. Suppose $\max\{cx|Ax\le b',x \text{ integral}\}$ and $\max\{cx|Ax\le b'',x \text{ integral}\}$ are finite. Then for each optimum solution $z'$ of the first maximum there exists an optimum solution $z''$ of the second maximum such that $\lVert z'-z''\rVert_{\infty}\le n\Delta (\lVert b'-b''\Vert_{\infty}+2)$.